# Apache not sending Last-Modified header even if explicitly set

Tags: apache

I have a problem with the Last-Modified header.

I created a simple test page:

```
<?
header('Last-Modified: Thu, 14 Feb 2013 12:41:31 GMT');
?>
```

When I open this test page with my browser, if I check the headers there's no Last-Modified header. All the other standard headers are set correctly. Anyway, if I access the test page with https, the Last-Modified header is set.

I also tried the same test on another server, and I can see the header correctly set even without https.

So, what could block/unset the header on the first server? I'm not including the httpd.conf file because is very long. I'll just include the caching section, even if I don't see anything wrong or related to this problem:

```
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod

Header unset ETag
FileETag None
<FilesMatch "(?i)^.*\.(ico|flv|jpe?g|png|gif|js|css).*$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public, no-transform"
    Header unset Vary:
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault A2592000
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it possible that some content is being sent before you call the `header()` function? It must be called before starting to send anything to the client.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
ssi off;
```

in nginx config for this domain

Answer (score -3):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the header, but using `<? ?>` instead of `<?php ?>` can cause problems on some servers.

Comment: They can cause problems because the configuration is set so that PHP requires `<?php ?>`. But this is not the case here, because his code works when using HTTPS.